# How do I refresh/reload a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm developing an extension in Chrome 4 (currently 4.0.249.0) that will show the user's StackOverflow/SuperUser/ServerFault reputation in the status bar. I've designed an options page to get the user's profile IDs and I save them to localStorage and read them well in the extension. It all works great.
The problem is I cannot find a (programmatic) way to refresh the extension upon options saving. I tried calling `location.reload();` from the extension page itself upon right clicking it - to no avail. I pursued it further and tried looking at what Chrome's `chrome://extensions/` page does to reload an extension, and found this code:

```
/**
 * Handles a 'reload' button getting clicked.
 */
function handleReloadExtension(node) {
  // Tell the C++ ExtensionDOMHandler to reload the extension.
  chrome.send('reload', [node.extensionId]);
}
```

Copying this code to my event handler did not help (and yes, I tried replacing `[node.extensionId]` with the actual code). Can someone please assist me in doing this the right way, or pointing me at a code of an extension that does this correctly? Once done, I'll put the extension and its source up on my blog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chrome.send function is not accessible by your extension's javascript code, pages like the newtab page, history and the extensions page use it to communicate with the C++ controller code for those pages.

You can push updates of your extension to users who have it installed, this is described [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html). The user's application will be updated once the autoupdate interval is hit or when they restart the browser. You cannot however reload a user's extension programmatically. I think that would be a security risk.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. Solved my problem by alerting the user to click my extension, which cause a redraw.

Comment: this question is kind of old, but now you can trigger reloads of extensions if you have access to the [extensions management API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html)

Comment: security risk? we get poor developer experience instead.

Answer (score 48):

Now the simplest way to make extension to **reload itself** is to call  [`chrome.runtime.reload()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-reload). This feature doesn't need any permissions in manifest.
To **reload another** extension use [`chrome.management.setEnabled()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-setEnabled). It requires *"permissions": [ "management" ]* in manifest.

Answer (score 6):

window.location.reload() works for me

I am using chromium 6.x so it might be fixed in newer version

Comment: I have used it within my background.js.
But you can use it from your views as well:
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().window.location.reload()

Comment: The background page is a "page" afterall.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this same problem with [an extension](https://github.com/joeyespo/inbox-by-gmail-checker).

Turns out you can listen for storage changes within `background.js` using [`chrome.storage.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#event-onChanged) and have that perform the refresh logic.

For example:

```
// Perform a reload any time the user clicks "Save"
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    profileId: 0
  }, function(items) {

    // Update status bar text here

  });
});
```

You could also reload *parts* of your extension this way by taking the `changes` parameter into account. `chrome.runtime.reload()` might be easier, but this has less overhead.

Answer (score 2):

For all future Googlers - the Browser Extension spec now includes `runtime.reload()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/reload

For Chrome, you might need to use `chrome.runtime.reload()` (but I'd handle such cases via Mozilla's awesome [`webextension-polyfill`](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill)).