# How do I auto-reload a Chrome extension I'm developing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like for my chrome extension to reload every time I save a file in the extension folder, without having to explicitly click "reload" in chrome://extensions/. Is this possible?

Edit: I'm aware I can [update the interval](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html) at which Chrome reloads extensions, which is a half-way solution, but I'd rather either making my editor (emacs or textmate) trigger on-save a reload or asking Chrome to monitor the directory for changes.

Comment: It seems to be faster when the reload is triggered from the ui enabled at chrome://flags/#enable-apps-devtool-app

Comment: I've forked [LiveJS](https://github.com/labofoz/Packaged-LiveJS) to allow for live reloading of Packaged Apps. Just include the file in your app and every time you save a file the app will autoreload.

Comment: Where is your LiveJS fork, @Oz Ramos?

Comment: Ah, I see: your "LiveJS" link is actually a linked to your fork, not to LiveJS.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as asked, but I want to mention that I stopped wanting this (or any other extension-loading-helper extension) after I realized I can easily reload an extension by hitting ctrl-R or cmd-R (depending on OS) in the extension's background window.  I find this fits into my workflow better than anything else I've tried, and it also avoids the problem of auto-reloading when files are in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Star [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=632011&q=reload%20component%3APlatform%3EExtensions&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) if you want a real solution to this problem.

Comment: I use the `web-ext` cli command from mozilla with the polyfill option. This allows plugins to run in both Firefox and Chrome and has an autoreload option. You have to develop in Firefox however, which I don't mind.

Comment: Quick disclaimer though, this won't reload the manifest.json ... see Google store comments ... https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid

Comment: @DonHatch, Where is the "extension's background window"?

Comment: The extension background window can be opened from the "Inspect views" list in the listing for your extension in chrome://extensions/.

Comment: @DonHatch what you mean by `background window` to press Ctrl+R to reload the extension? in web page, it refresh the page itself (not extension). in background service page it doesn't do anything. may be i didn't get exact place you mean

Comment: @S.Serpooshan what Denis Howe said.  chrome://extenstions and find the extension you are interested in, there should be a "Inspect views" list, with a "background page" link; click on that and, usually it will just bring up devtools with that extension's console log.  When I hit ctrl-R in that console window (after maybe clicking on it first to give it keyboard focus), the extension reloads.

Comment: @DonHatch thanks for explanation, but i can't see this to work! as i said, when i press Ctrl+R in background page (DevTools that attached to background service) nothing happens. i test focusing different tabs before pressing the shortcut key eg its Console or Sources tabs but nothing happen.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You can use **"[Extensions Reloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid)"** for Chrome:

> **Reloads all unpacked extensions using the extension's toolbar button or by browsing to "http://reload.extensions"**
>
> If you've ever developed a Chrome extension, you might have wanted to
>   automate the process of reloading your unpacked extension without the
>   need of going through the extensions page.
>
> "Extensions Reloader" allows you to reload all unpacked extensions 
>   using 2 ways:
>
> 1 - The extension's toolbar button.
>
> 2 - Browsing to "http://reload.extensions".
>
> The toolbar icon will reload unpacked extensions using a single click.
>
> The "reload by browsing" is intended for automating the reload process
>   using "post build" scripts - just add a browse to
>   "http://reload.extensions" using Chrome to your script, and you'll
>   have a refreshed Chrome window.

**Update:** As of January 14, 2015, the extension is open-sourced and [available on GitHub](https://github.com/arikw/chrome-extensions-reloader).

Comment: This is the best solution so far, but it still doesn't make it easy to update the extension every time I modify a file it's using, which is what I was ideally looking.

Comment: Thanks. Wanted to mention that I use PhpStorm and that I added a toolbar button that calls chrome.exe with the "reload.extensions" url. Whenever I want to test the code, I press that button and Chrome popups up with the updated addon.

Comment: Good call. I guess you could also make a simple script to make that call when there are changes to files used by the script. Still surprised Chrome can't do it by itself, though :-P

Comment: Woaw, I just managed to get [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) to work with this plugin by using [grunt-open](https://github.com/onehealth/grunt-open) to open `http://reload.extensions` when a file gets modified. It now acts exactly like livereload, but with an anoying chrome window opening each time I modify one of the specified plugin files :P. Thanks!

Comment: @GabLeRoux I came here just to find if someone already did it. It works like a charm.

Comment: @GabLeRoux Can you share a snippet, I am new to grunt and that sounds very useful. The think I am not seeing right away is how to trigger the open on file change. Thx!

Comment: @studgeek Here you go: http://pastebin.com/Hef6nQvw I was doing some tricky things (using chrome canary) but you should be fine with this file. Open on file change is done using [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) with livereload enabled, see [livereload chrome plugin](http://goo.gl/jqZ1z6)

Comment: Thanks for the idea @GabLeRoux. I did the same using [gulp-open](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-open).

Comment: Unfortunately chrome doesn't provide proper API to reload an extension. This approach closes the Devtools of background page

Comment: @GabLeRoux  so how can we (re)load `http://reload.extensions` without opening a new tab/window ??

Comment: @AlexanderMills sadly I wasn't able to do it without opening a new tab each time. If you find a better solution. At least, one can reload plugins with the https://github.com/arikw/chrome-extensions-reloader

Comment: what is the best way in 2019?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper the "Extensions Reloader" extension mentioned here still works very well. I just installed [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) and am running `fswatch -o * | xargs -n1 -I{} open http://reload.extensions` in the terminal and it works perfectly. Yay! Thank you all!!

Comment: This is awesome. I got it working with a `gulp watch` script and its " Reload current tab after extensions have been reloaded." to refresh my extension and refresh the page when I click the button in the toolbar.

Comment: April 2020: This seems no longer to work, issue here https://github.com/arikw/chrome-extensions-reloader/issues/12

Comment: Version v1.15 released with bug fixes

Answer (score 66):

**Update**: I have added an options page, so that you don't have to manually find and edit the extension's ID any more. [CRX](https://github.com/Rob--W/Chrome-Extension-Reloader/blob/master/Chrome-Extension-Reloader.crx) and source code are at: https://github.com/Rob--W/Chrome-Extension-Reloader
Update 2: Added shortcut (see my repository on Github).
<sub>*The original code, which includes the **basic functionality** is shown below*.</sub>

---

Create an extension, and use the [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) method in conjunction with the [`chrome.extension.management`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) API to reload your unpacked extension.

The code below adds a button to Chrome, which will reload an extension upon click.

### `manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "Chrome Extension Reloader",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {"scripts": ["bg.js"] },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon48.png",
        "default_title": "Reload extension"
    },
    "permissions": ["management"]
}
```

### `bg.js`

```
var id = "<extension_id here>";
function reloadExtension(id) {
    chrome.management.setEnabled(id, false, function() {
        chrome.management.setEnabled(id, true);
    });
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    reloadExtension(id);
});
```

**`icon48.png`**: Pick any nice 48x48 icon, for example:
[image: Google Chrome]
 [image: Google Chrome]

Comment: @trusktr Scott's answer only reloads the background page. However, both answers can be combines (Scotts answer + helper extension), so that an extension is automatically reload when an extension's file changes. I do, however recommend against this practice, since the devtools are closed upon extension reload. I often fiddle with a test extension, and frequently save my changes, even when the syntax is incomplete. That would crash my extension, if a real auto-reload is enabled.

Comment: @RobW Good point. I often save in the middle of writing code so the code will definitely break the plugin in question.

Comment: @Sudarshan You [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1235128) to use `chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id")`. This, however returns the extensionID of the *current* extension, which is not useful because an extension cannot reload itself using the `management` API (after disabling, it doesn't have a chance to enable the extension again).

Answer (score 55):

in any function or event

```
chrome.runtime.reload();
```

will reload your extension ([docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-reload)). You also need to change the **manifest.json** file, adding:

```
...
"permissions": [ "management" , ...]
...
```

Comment: for me this solution only worked if I wrote chrome.runtime.reload() in the script in the index.html where is specified in the manifest file in the follow way:     ** "background": { "page": "index.html", ** .    In my content_script js file, I couldn't access this function. I believe, it is for security reseons.

Comment: Your content script can't talk to chrome APIs. For that to work you need to [use messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

Comment: when you call `chrome.runtime.reload()`, what actually happens? do multiple pages/tabs refresh?

Comment: I am guessing we should call `chrome.runtime.reload()` from the background script

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: is there a way to connect to websocket server from the background.js script?

Answer (score 54):

I've made a simple embeddable script doing hot reload:

**https://github.com/xpl/crx-hotreload**

It watches for file changes in an extension's directory. When a change detected, it reloads the extension and refreshes the active tab (to re-trigger updated content scripts).

- Works by checking timestamps of files
- Supports nested directories
- Automatically disables itself in the production configuration

Comment: If you are looking for a "gulp flavored" solution, this is it.

Comment: worked great. Have you considered making an npm package?

Comment: @pixelearth yeah, why not. Hmm, but what would be the use case then? You `npm install crx-hotreload` into the extension's directory, and then reference the script like `"scripts": ["./node_modules/crx-hotreload/hot-reload.js"]`? Correct me if I wrong.

Comment: @pixelearth so here's the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crx-hotreload

I would be very grateful if you could help me with README.md update on how to correctly use the script when installed from NPM

Comment: @MilfordCubicle I would suggest exporting an object that has a method that you could call in your background.js file. So something `import reloader from 'hot-reload'` then in the script reloader.check()

Comment: ah just saw that you posted a package. Good on you. Thanks!

Comment: The answer needs more upvotes. Works well in combination with Webpack `--watch` as well, because you can just put it in your build folder so it only updates after the build process has finished. No complicated Webpack post-build command plugins.

Comment: This is the way. Super easy to implement thank you @VitalyGordon!

Comment: Doesn't work with manifest version 3

Comment: As @polendina stated this is not working in manifest v3 because `chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry` for new manifest.

Answer (score 29):

I am using a shortcut to reload. I don't want to reload all the time when I save a file

So my approach is lightweight, and you can leave the reload function in

**manifest.json**

```
{
    ...
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "src/bg/background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "commands": {
        "Ctrl+M": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+M",
                "mac": "Command+M"
            },
            "description": "Ctrl+M."
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

**src/bg/background.js**

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((shortcut) => {
    console.log('lets reload');
    console.log(shortcut);
    if(shortcut.includes("+M")) {
        chrome.runtime.reload();
    }
})
```

Now press Ctrl + M in the chrome browser to reload

Comment: You can also use the reload function in the browserAction so that it will reload on the button click. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427908/how-can-i-reload-my-chrome-extension-by-javascript/

Comment: Yes you can load chrome.runtime.reload() everywher. I use: editor > ctrl + s > alt + tab > ctrl + m. Having background..js console open. Its fast, without using a mouse

Comment: This is perfect. Just modify code in editor (mine is VS Code), Alt Tab to any chrome window (not necessary background console), and Ctrl M.

When developing contentscript with DOM modification, It is `Alt Tab, Ctrl M, Ctrl R` (to reload the `main world` page).

Comment: I think this is the simplest and great solution among all

Comment: This solution should be at top!

Comment: Does this include any new files you add to the extension, or manifest changes?

Answer (score 16):

### TL;DR

Create a WebSocket server that dispatches a message to a background script that can handle the update. If you are using webpack and don't plan to do it yourself, [webpack-run-chrome-extension](https://github.com/cezaraugusto/webpack-run-chrome-extension) can help.

### Answer

You can create a WebSocket server to communicate with the extension as a WebSocket client (via `window` object). The extension would then listen for file changes by attaching the WebSocket server to some listener mechanism (like webpack devServer).

Did the file change? Set the server to dispatch a message to the extension asking for updates (broadcasting the ws message to the client(s)). The extension then reloads, replies with "ok, reloaded" and keeps listening for new changes.

[image]

### Plan

1. Set up a WebSocket server (to dispatch update requests)
2. Find a service that can tell you when did the files change (webpack/other bundler software)
3. When an update happens, dispatch a message to client requesting updates
4. Set up a WebSocket client (to receive update requests)
5. Reload the extension

### How

For the WebSocket server, use [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws). For file changes, use some listener/hook (like webpack's [`watchRun`](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#watchrun) hook). For the client part, [native WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket). The extension could then attach the WebSocket client on a background script for keeping sync persistent between the server (hosted by webpack) and the client (the script attached in the extension background).

Now, to make the extension reload itself, you can either call `chrome.runtime.reload()` in it each time the upload request message comes from the server, or even create a "reloader extension" that would do that for you, using `chrome.management.setEnabled()` (requires `"permissions": [ "management" ]` in manifest).

In the ideal scenario, tools like [`webpack-dev-server`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) or any other web server software could offer support for `chrome-extension` URLs natively. Until that happens, having a server to proxy file changes to your extension seems to be the best option so far.

### Available open-source alternative

If you are using webpack and don't want to create it all yourself, I made [webpack-run-chrome-extension](https://github.com/cezaraugusto/webpack-run-chrome-extension), which does what I planned above.

Answer (score 11):

Another solution would be to create custom livereload script (extension-reload.js):

```
// Reload client for Chrome Apps & Extensions.
// The reload client has a compatibility with livereload.
// WARNING: only supports reload command.

var LIVERELOAD_HOST = 'localhost:';
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + LIVERELOAD_HOST + LIVERELOAD_PORT + '/livereload');

connection.onerror = function (error) {
  console.log('reload connection got error:', error);
};

connection.onmessage = function (e) {
  if (e.data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (data && data.command === 'reload') {
      chrome.runtime.reload();
    }
  }
};
```

This script connects to the livereload server using websockets. Then, it will issue a chrome.runtime.reload() call upon reload message from livereload. The next step would be to add this script to run as background script in your manifest.json, and voila!

Note: this is not my solution. I'm just posting it. I found it in the generated code of [Chrome Extension generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-chrome-extension) (Great tool!). I'm posting this here because it might help.

Answer (score 11):

The great guys at mozilla just released a new https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext that you can use to launch `web-ext run --target chromium`

Comment: This is the best solution for me. I also use it to sign my extension

Answer (score 9):

Chrome Extensions have a [permission system](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) that it wouldn't allow it (some people in SO [had the same problem as you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761799/how-do-i-refresh-relaod-a-chrome-extension)), so requesting them to "add this feature" is not going to work IMO. There's a mail from Chromium Extensions Google Groups with a [proposed solution (theory)](http://www.mail-archive.com/chromium-extensions@googlegroups.com/msg01874.html) using `chrome.extension.getViews()`, but is not guaranteed to work either.

If it was possible to add to the `manifest.json` some Chrome internal pages like `chrome://extensions/`, it would be possible to create a plugin that would interact to the `Reload` anchor, and, using an external program like [XRefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/) (a Firefox Plugin - there's a [Chrome version](http://gist.github.com/342682) using Ruby and WebSocket), you would achieve just what you need:

> XRefresh is a browser plugin which
>   will refresh current web page due to
>   file change in selected folders. This
>   makes it possible to do live page
>   editing with your favorite HTML/CSS
>   editor.

It's not possible to do it, but I think you can use this same concept in a different way.

You could try to find third-party solutions instead that, after seeing modifications in a file (I don't know emacs neither Textmate, but in Emacs it would be possible to bind an app call within a "save file" action), just clicks in an specific coordinate of an specific application: in this case it's the `Reload` anchor from your extension in development (you leave a Chrome windows opened just for this reload).

(Crazy as hell but it may work)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a function that you can use to watch files for changes, and reload if changes are detected. It works by polling them via AJAX, and reloading via window.location.reload(). I suppose you shouldn't use this in a distribution package.

```
function reloadOnChange(url, checkIntervalMS) {
    if (!window.__watchedFiles) {
        window.__watchedFiles = {};
    }

    (function() {
        var self = arguments.callee;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (__watchedFiles[url] &&
                    __watchedFiles[url] != xhr.responseText) {
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    __watchedFiles[url] = xhr.responseText
                    window.setTimeout(self, checkIntervalMS || 1000);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send();
    })();
}

reloadOnChange(chrome.extension.getURL('/myscript.js'));
```

Comment: Can do, add: reloadOnChange(chrome.extension.getURL('/manifest.json'));

Comment: I've tried http://pastebin.com/mXbSPkeu, but the extension is **not** updated (manifest entries, content script, browser action) (Ubuntu 11.10, Chrome 18). The **only** updated file is the background page (changed `console.log` messages do show up).

Comment: "watch files for changes, and reload if changes are detected." For the life of me I cannot see how this would know that a file has changed?  Please help me understand as it sounds awesome!

Comment: oo I see now, it's storing a copy of the files content and comparing the cached version with the ajax live version....clever!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I'm a little late to the party, but I've solved it for me by creating https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-unpacked-extension/fddfkmklefkhanofhlohnkemejcbamln

It works by reloading `chrome://extensions` page, whenever `file.change` events are incoming via websockets.

A Gulp-based example of how to emit `file.change` event upon file changes in an extension folder can be found here: https://github.com/robin-drexler/chrome-extension-auto-reload-watcher

Why reloading the entire tab instead of just using the extensions management api to reload/re-enable extensions? Currently disabling and enabling extensions again causes any open inspection window (console log etc.) to close, which I found to be too annoying during active development.

Comment: nice! I see you have a PR for a new upgraded reload() function.

Answer (score 5):

There's an automatic reload plugin if you're developing using webpack:
https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/webpack-chrome-extension-reloader

```
const ChromeExtensionReloader = require('webpack-chrome-extension-reloader');

plugins: [
    new ChromeExtensionReloader()
]
```

Also comes with a CLI tool if you don't want to modify webpack.config.js:

```
npx wcer
```

Note: an (empty) background script is required even if you don't need it because that's where it injects reload code.

Comment: Archived already :( pointing to https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/webpack-extension-reloader which is cross browser, and still in active development though :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit late answer but I think [crxreload](https://github.com/wader/crxreload) might work for you. It's my result of trying to have a reload-on-save workflow while developing.

Answer (score 3):

Use `npm init` to create a package.json in directory root, then

`npm install --save-dev gulp-open && npm install -g gulp`

then create a `gulpfile.js`

which looks like:

```
/* File: gulpfile.js */

// grab our gulp packages
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    open = require('gulp-open');

// create a default task and just log a message
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

// configure which files to watch and what tasks to use on file changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('extensionData/userCode/**/*.js', ['uri']);
});

gulp.task('uri', function(){
  gulp.src(__filename)
  .pipe(open({uri: "http://reload.extensions"}));
});
```

This works for me developing with CrossRider, you might watch to change the path you watch the files at, also assuming you have npm and node installed.

Answer (score 2):

Your content files such has html and manifest files are not changeable without installation of the extension, but I do believe that the JavaScript files are dynamically loaded until the extension has been packed.

I know this because of a current project im working on via the Chrome Extensions API, and seems to load every-time i refresh a page.

Comment: I don't know what version you were using, but as 16.0.912.63 m, Chrome reloads all files automatically. Except the manifest.

Comment: @Zequez: The files are not reloaded for me. :(

Comment: You are right. I was developing the Options page, which calls the scripts from withing the document, and therefore reloading them. The content_script scripts are not reloaded =/

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I developed this extension myself.

### [Clerc - for Chrome Live Extension Reloading Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clerc/dncedehofgbacgaojmingbdfogecjjbj)

> Connect to a LiveReload compatible server to automatically reload your extension every time you save.
>
> Bonus: with a little extra work on your part, you can also automatically reload the webpages that your extension alters.

Most webpage developers use a build system with some sort of watcher that automatically builds their files and restarts their server and reloads the website.

Developing extensions shouldn't need to be that different. Clerc brings this same automation to Chrome devs. Set up a build system with a LiveReload server, and Clerc will listen for reload events to refresh your extension.

The only big gotcha is changes to the manifest.json. Any tiny typos in the manifest will probably cause further reload attempts to fail, and you will be stuck uninstalling/reinstalling your extension to get your changes loading again.

Clerc forwards the complete reload message to your extension after it reloads, so you can optionally use the provided message to trigger further refresh steps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @GmonC and @Arik and some spare time, I managet to get this working. I have had to change two files to make this work.

(1) Install LiveReload and Chrome Extension for that application. 
This will call some script on file change.

(2) Open `<LiveReloadInstallDir>\Bundled\backend\res\livereload.js`

(3) change line `#509` to

`this.window.location.href = "http://reload.extensions";`

(4) Now install another extension `Extensions Reloader` which has useful link handler that reload all development extensions on navigating to `"http://reload.extensions"`

(5) Now change that extension's `background.min.js` in this way

`if((d.installType=="development")&&(d.enabled==true)&&(d.name!="Extensions Reloader"))`

replace with

```
if((d.installType=="development")&&(d.enabled==true)&&(d.name!="Extensions Reloader")&&(d.name!="LiveReload"))
```

Open LiveReload application, hide Extension Reloader button and activate LiveReload extension by clicking on button in toolbar, you will now reload page and extensions on each file change while using all other goodies from LiveReload (css reload, image reload etc.)

Only bad thing about this is that you will have to repeat procedure of changing scripts on every extension update. To avoid updates, add extension as unpacked.

When I'll have more time to mess around with this, I probably will create extension that eliminates need for both of these extensions.

Untill then, I'm working on my extension [Projext Axeman](http://justbuild.github.com/Project-Axeman/)

Answer (score 1):

Just found a newish [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) based project that provides bootstrapping, scaffolding, some automated pre-processing faculty, as well as auto-reloading (no interaction needed).

[Bootstrap Your Chrome Extension](http://blog.websecurify.com/2013/09/chrome-extension-development-simplified.html) from Websecurify

Answer (score 1):

I want to reload (update) my extensions overnight, this is what I use in background.js:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
var untilnight = (n == 0) ? 24*3600000 : (24-n)*3600000; 
// refresh after 24 hours if hour = 0 else
// refresh after 24-n hours (that will always be somewhere between 0 and 1 AM)
setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
}, untilnight);
```

Regards, 
Peter

Answer (score 1):

I primarily develop in Firefox, where `web-ext run` automatically reloads the extension after files change. Then once it's ready, I do a final round of testing in Chrome to make sure there aren't any issues that didn't show up in Firefox.

If you want to develop primarily in Chrome, though, and don't want to install any 3rd party extensions, then another option is to create a  `test.html` file in the extension's folder, and add a bunch of [SSCCE's](http://sscce.org/) to it. That file then uses a normal `<script>` tag to inject the extension script.

You could use that for 95% of testing, and then manually reload the extension when you want to test it on live sites.

That doesn't identically reproduce the environment that an extension runs in, but it's good enough for many simple things.

Comment: You are now able to run in chromium also: "web-ext run -t chromium"

Answer (score 1):

### MAC ONLY

**Using [Extensions Reloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid)**:

#### Using Typescript

1. Add the watcher of your to your project: `yarn add tsc-watch`
2. Add command to `scripts` to `package.json`

```json
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"open -a '/Applications/Google Chrome.app' 'http://reload.extensions'\""
  },
...
```

3. Run script `yarn dev`

#### Using JavaScript

1. Add the watcher of your to your project: `yarn add watch-cli`
2. Add command to `scripts` to `package.json`

```json
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "watch -p \"**/*.js\" -c \"open -a '/Applications/Google Chrome.app' 'http://reload.extensions'\""
  },
...
```

3. Run script `yarn dev`

**Bonus**: Turn on 'reload current tab' in Extensions Reloader options, so it reloads after a change was made:

[image]

Comment: Do I understand correctly that each file change in the project, will be interrupted by opening Chrome on the `http://reload.extensions`?

Comment: It actually doesn't open chrome every time. If its already open the extension will just be reloaded and a new tab is not opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can reload the extension by calling `chrome.runtime.reload()`. If you want to reload the extension automatically on each build, you can set up a script to poll for changes.

Here's an example with a package.json file:

```
// package.json
// public is the folder containing the unpacked extension
{
  "name": "package-name",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "build-and-reload": "echo $(date +%s) > public/.timestamp && npm run build"
  }
}
```

```js
// background.ts


import { log } from "./log";

export const initAutoUpdater = () => {
  log("initAutoUpdater");
  const loop = async () => {
    const currentTS = await fetch("./.timestamp").then((_) => _.json());

    while (true) {
      log("checking for updates...");
      const newTS = await fetch("./.timestamp")
        .then((_) => _.json())
        .catch(() => "unknown");
      if (newTS === "unknown" || newTS === currentTS) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      } else {
        log(`new update found! ${new Date(currentTS)} -> ${new Date(newTS)}`);
        chrome.runtime.reload();
        return;
      }
    }
  };

  loop();
};
```

Here's how I use it:

1. I have a build task mapped to CMD+shift+B in VSCode
2. on each build we re-generate the .timestamp file with the current Unix timestamp
3. background.js polls for that file and compares it with the version it accessed on first load (`req.json()` works as `Number` is a valid JSON value)
4. if the timestamp is different, we reload the runtime

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vite, here is a simple Vite [plugin](https://github.com/isaurssaurav/hot-reload-extension-vite) to reload the chrome extension when developing for mv3.

Usage

```
$ npm i hot-reload-extension-vite -D
```

```js
import hotReloadExtension from 'hot-reload-extension-vite';

export default {
  plugins: [
    hotReloadExtension({
      log: true,
      backgroundPath: 'path/to/background' // src/pages/background/index.ts
    })
  ]
};
```

Then run

```
$ NODE_ENV=development vite build --watch
```

Extension and your tab will reload when vite detects file change.

Answer (score 0):

I've forked [LiveJS](https://github.com/labofoz/Packaged-LiveJS) to allow for live reloading of Packaged Apps. Just include the file in your app and every time you save a file the app will autoreload.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs: the following command line will reload an app

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --load-and-launch-app=[path to the app ]
```

so I just created a shell script and called that file from gulp. Super simple:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;



gulp.task('reload-chrome-build',function(cb){

console.log("reload");

var cmd="./reloadchrome.sh"

exec(cmd,function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("done: "+stdout);

    cb(err);
    }
);});
```

run your necessary watch commands on scripts and call the reload task when you want to. Clean, simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is where software such as AutoIt or alternatives shine. The key is writing a script which emulates your current testing phase. Get used to using at least one of them as many technologies do not come with clear workflow/testing paths.

```
Run("c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
WinWaitActive("New Tab - Google Chrome")
Send("^l")
Send("chrome://extensions{ENTER}")
WinWaitActive("Extensions - Google Chrome")
Send("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")
Send("{ENTER}")
WinWaitActive("Extensions - Google Chrome")
Send("{TAB}{TAB}")
Send("{ENTER}")
WinWaitActive("Developer Tools")
Send("^`")
```

Obviously you change the code to suit your testing/iterating needs. Make sure tab clicks are true to where the anchor tag is in the chrome://extensions site. You could also use relative to window mouse movements and other such macros.

I would add the script to Vim in a way similar to this:

```
map <leader>A :w<CR>:!{input autoit loader exe here} "{input script location here}"<CR>
```

This means that when I'm in Vim I press the button above ENTER (usually responsible for: | and \) known as the leader button and follow it with a capital 'A' and it saves and begins my testing phase script.

Please make sure to fill in the {input...} sections in the above Vim/hotkey script appropriately.

Many editors will allow you to do something similar with hotkeys.

Alternatives to [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) can be found [here](http://alternativeto.net/software/autoit/).

For Windows: AutoHotkey

For Linux: xdotool, xbindkeys

For Mac: Automator

Answer (score 0):

**If you have a Mac, ¡the easiest way is with Alfred App!**

Just get *Alfred App with Powerpack*, then add the workflow provided in the link below and customise the hotkey you want (I like to use ⌘ + ⌥ + R). That's all.

Now, every time you use the hotkey, *Google Chrome* will reload, no matter which application you're at that moment.

If you want to use other browser, open the AppleScript inside Alfred Preferences Workflows and replace "Google Chrome" with "Firefox", "Safari", ...

I also will show here the content of the **/usr/bin/osascript** script used in the *ReloadChrome.alfredworkflow file* so you can see what it is doing.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
  activate
  delay 0.5
  tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using command down
  delay 0.5
  tell application "System Events" to keystroke tab using command down
end tell
```

The workflow file is [ReloadChrome.alfredworkflow](http://nitroflare.com/view/20BCC03C472BEB2/ReloadChrome.alfredworkflow).

Answer (score 0):

The author recommended the next version of that webpack plugin: https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/webpack-extension-reloader. It works very well for me.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,you can do it indirectly! Here is my solution.

In manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "content_scripts":[{
        "run_at":"document_end",
        "matches":["http://*/*"],
        "js":["/scripts/inject.js"]
    }]
}
```

In inject.js

```
(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script'); 
    script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    script.async = true;
    script.src = 'Your_Scripts';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
})();
```

Your injected script can inject other script from any location.

Another benefit from this technic is that you can just ignore the limitation of **isolated world**. see [content script execution environment](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)

Comment: Not working for me?  If I try script.src = 'foo.js', it looks for a url relative to the current website.  If I try the full path I get:  Not allowed to load local resource: 'file:///../foo.js'

Answer (score -2):

**BROWSER-SYNC**

Using the amazing [Browser-Sync](https://browsersync.io)

- update browsers (any) when source code changes (HTML, CSS, images, etc.)
- support Windows, MacOS and Linux
- you could even watch your code updates (live) using your mobile devices

**Instalation on MacOS** (view their help to install on other OS)

Install NVM, so you can try any Node version

```
brew install nvm             # install a Node version manager
nvm ls-remote                # list available Node versions
nvm install v10.13.0         # install one of them
npm install -g browser-sync  # install Browser-Sync
```

**How to use browser-sync for static sites**

Let's see two examples:

```
browser-sync start --server --files . --host YOUR_IP_HERE --port 9000

browser-sync start --server --files $(ack --type-add=web:ext:htm,html,xhtml,js,css --web -f | tr \\n \ ) --host $(ipconfig getifaddr en0) --port 9000
```

The `--server` option allow you to run a local server anywhere you are in your terminal and `--files` let you specify which files will be tracked for changes. I prefer to be more specific for the tracked files, so in the second example I use `ack` for listing specific file extensions (is important that those files do not have filenames with spaces) and also use`ipconfig` to find my current IP on MacOS.

**How to use browser-sync for dynamic sites**

In case you are using PHP, Rails, etc., you already have a running server, but it doesn't refresh automatically when you make changes to your code. So you need to use the `--proxy` switch to let browser-sync know where is the host for that server.

```
browser-sync start --files $(ack --type-add=rails:ext:rb,erb,js,css,sass,scss,coffee --rails -f | tr \\n \ ) --proxy 192.168.33.12:3000 --host $(ipconfig getifaddr en0) --port 9000 --no-notify --no-open
```

In the above example, I already have a Rails app running on my browser on  `192.168.33.12:3000`. It really runs on a VM using a Vagrant box, but I could access the virtual machine using port 3000 on that host. I like `--no-notify` to stop browser-sync sending me a notification alert on the browser every time I change my code and `--no-open` to stop browser-sync behavior that immediately loads a browser tab when the server start.

**IMPORTANT:** Just in case you're using Rails, avoid using Turbolinks on development, otherwise you will not be able click on your links while using the `--proxy` option.

Hope it would be useful to someone. I've tried many tricks to refresh the browser (even an old post I've submitted on this StackOverflow question using AlfredApp time ago), but this is really the way to go; no more hacks, it just flows.

**CREDIT:** [Start a local live reload web server with one command](https://medium.com/@svinkle/start-a-local-live-reload-web-server-with-one-command-72f99bc6e855)

Answer (score -7):

It can't be done directly.  Sorry.

If you would like to see it as a feature you can request it at http://crbug.com/new

Comment: It can be done, this isn't a proper answer. Just a look at the other answers and they will tell you that.