# Chrome extensions: unpacked extension caching

Tags: google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-extension

I'm starting development on a chrome extension and have run into caching issues of the extension resources.

So far, my development cycle goes like this: I make a change in any file - manifest.json, background pages, content scripts, popups - save it, reload the extension in the Extensions tab, and the test it out.

That works about half of the time.  The other half requires me either to reload the link multiple times in the Extensions tab, close down the browser completely to reload it, or sometimes even delete the extension and then load it back again with the "Load Unpacked Extensions" button.

This caching has been very frustrating and I've lost a lot of time to it already... has anyone had a similar experience, and if so, found a solution?

BTW: I have "Disable cache" already checked under 'Developer Tools > Little gear icon' and it hasn't helped in any way that I'm aware of.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is it that you think is being cached? I have no problems only reloading the extension once to make changes.

Comment: I've had the manifest.js file cache after a reload, as well as both background and content scripts.  I'm currently dealing with a separate JS file (reference in my popup.html file) caching so hard that I can't get it to update at all.  Hoping I could figure out why.

Comment: One interesting think I've noticed: I can almost always fully refresh my chrome extension cache if I first reload, then open/close the devtools for the extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Faster way to modify chrome extension than Remove -> Load unpacked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159273/faster-way-to-modify-chrome-extension-than-remove-load-unpacked)