# Rapid chrome extension development

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I auto-reload a Chrome extension I'm developing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963260/how-do-i-auto-reload-a-chrome-extension-im-developing)

Let me know, does something exist for rapid chrome extension development? At the moment, thing that drives me crazy is a need to refresh unpacked extension every time i've made some changes to files.
Does something exist for auto refresh extension after changing files state?

Thanks!

Comment: See [How do I auto-reload a Chrome extension I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9645435/938089?how-do-i-auto-reload-a-chrome-extension-im-developing) (https://github.com/Rob--W/Chrome-Extension-Reloader).

Comment: Idea is ok, but I will not install an extension that is not on the official google chrome market. Possibly author collects some information about pages I visit or data, I fill on different sites, including PayPal, Western Union or so on.

Comment: Well then it's a good thing that his source code is available and only 100 lines long, this way you can review it yourself before using it.

Comment: @InviS You can [download the crx file](https://github.com/Rob--W/Chrome-Extension-Reloader/blob/master/Chrome-Extension-Reloader.crx), unzip it (a crx file is just a signed zip file), and look in the source code. Alternatively, you can browse the [source code](https://github.com/Rob--W/Chrome-Extension-Reloader/tree/master/Chrome-Extension-Reloader), and pack/load the extension yourself. Last note, the base code of the extension is also included in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9645435/938089?how-do-i-auto-reload-a-chrome-extension-im-developing), if you don't trust GitHub.

Comment: yep, thanks. But what is a problem to place it in the market and let others use it?
Also, is it possible to provide a shortcut for extension reload? click there isn't always convenient.

Comment: @InviS The last time I attempted to register a Chrome extension, I had to pay 5$ with Google Checkout as the only payment option. Providing a shorcut is possible, but not worth the slight overhead (and it's not 100% reliable).

Comment: It could be optional :) As for me - inconvenient click icon every time - much quicker is switch tabs (cmd+opt+left/right) and reload extensions. Thanks for extension :)