# Chrome extensions in development auto reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I saw this question: [How do I auto-reload a Chrome extension I'm developing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963260/how-do-i-auto-reload-a-chrome-extension-im-developing)

But I didn't find anything useful there. I tried to get something working bu I don't like it very much. There must be some other way by now, it has been 2 years since initial question was asked.

So, is there any application or extension that would allow me to reload extension on file change?

Comment: That, however, is not quite how SO works. To request updated answers, the customary path is a bounty. Now we have a situation when users post identical answers on both and get slapped by moderators. Dupehammering this.

Comment: @Xan Thanks. Didn't quite undestand how SO works back then.

Comment: No problem! But because we have a demonstrable case where this leads to copy-paste answering, it's best to close it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Tincr](http://tin.cr/). It allows you to edit/save the code directly in browser and auto-reload on changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **"[Extensions Reloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid)"** for Chrome:

> **Reload all unpacked extensions using the extension's toolbar button or by browsing to "http://reload.extensions"**
>
> If you've ever developed a Chrome extension, you might have wanted to
>   automate the process of reloading your unpacked extension without the
>   need of going through the extensions page.
>
> "Extensions Reloader" allows you to reload all unpacked extensions
>
> using 2 ways:
>   1 - The extension's toolbar button.
>   2 - Browsing to "http://reload.extensions".
>
> The toolbar icon will reload unpacked extensions using a single click.
>
> The "reload by browsing" is intended for automating the reload process
>   using "post build" scripts - just add a browse to
>   "http://reload.extensions" using Chrome to your script, and you'll
>   have a refreshed Chrome window.