# How to reload a chrome extension automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension, and I found that there are repeating useless manual reloading works.

When you save a file, you have to refresh the `chrome:\\extensions` page to let browser to reload the extension. And then you have to reload the test page to see if the changes to files take effect.

I am newbie to Chrome extension development. And are there any ways to reduce the repeating works? I am also curious that what is the best practice of chrome extension development workflow.

Poor English, feel free to correct.

Comment: should be `chrome://extensions`, right ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor You're right, I updated it.

Comment: You can see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963260/how-do-i-auto-reload-a-chrome-extension-im-developing

Comment: @user2666750 What I need is that when you save the file, the browser will automatically refresh without even a click on the toolbar. Something like `grunt-watch`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The extension can reload itself, by calling **[`chrome.runtime.reload()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-reload)**, so it's a matter of triggering the extension to do it.

One method that worked for me, is to watch for tabs' **[`onUpdated`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated)** event and look for a specific URL (you have come up with), e.g. `http://localhost/reloadX?id=...`.

This is the sample code (to be placed in **background.js**):

```
var myReloadURL = 'http://localhost/reloadX?id='
                  + chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id');

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.url === myReloadURL) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
        chrome.runtime.reload();
    }
});
```

Additional permissions (to be declared in **manifest.json**):

```
...
"permissions": [
    ...
    "tabs",
    "http://localhost/reloadX?id=*"
```

<sub>`myReloadURL` is arbitrary and can be any URL, just doesn't have to be a real URL or the resource will be rendered unreachable.</sub>

Now, in order to reload your extension, you need to open the following address in Chrome:
`http://localhost/reloadX?id=<your_extension_id>`

It is up to you to choose how to trigger that on save. It could be an `on-save` hook in your editor, a custom grunt-watch task (since you  seem to be familiar with grunt) etc .

---

(BTW, you don't need to reload the `chrome://extensions` page. It suffices to reload the extension.)

Comment: I have solve this problem by using `grunt` and `Extension Reloader`, but it's very tricky. Your way is more elegant. Nice answer, thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

I built [Clerc](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clerc/dncedehofgbacgaojmingbdfogecjjbj) to work out-of-the-box with any LiveReload server. Just include any LiveReload compatible watcher in your build process and Clerc will take care of reloading.

Answer (score 0):

I have to reveal this because it is little bit more boiled down for dummies (->miself) than gkalpak's solution but is based on that. This uses a plain bookmark to reload Chrome extension. 
As prerequisite an Apache is running at port 80.

1. Create a bookmark at bookmark bar with real functioning localhost url: 'http://localhost/subdir/reload_dummy.php'. 
   That php file was empty. You can change the url to be any valid url on the web to match your need.
2. Add webRequest permission item to manifest.json:

   "permissions":[
       "webRequest","tabs"],

Then copy some code to background.js:

```
var reloadURL = 'http://localhost/subdir/reload_dummy.php';
var cbBeforeRequest = function (info) {

    if (info.url === reloadURL) {
          chrome.runtime.reload();
           alert("HiiHaa!:" + info.url);
    }

}
var filters = {urls: [reloadURL]};
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(cbBeforeRequest, filters);
```