# Google Chrome: updating extension in "Developer mode" (locally) from userscript

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created an extension for Google Chrome which runs a small userscript for designated web-page and makes some requests via *background.js* to the chrome APIs (such chrome.tabs and others).

now, I'm testing it locally in "Developer mode" like this:

1. I edit my *userscript.js* and *background.js*;
2. then I go to **chrome://extensions** tab in Google Chrome and manually reload (CTR+R) my extension from local *D:\my-extension* folder.
3. finally, I switch to the tab with designated web-page and reload it to see the changes.

the problem is:
since I'm a beginner, a lot of changes have to be done to my *userscript.js* and *background.js* before my extension and userscript start working as expected. 
so, this process involves a lot of monotonous switching between extensions and page tabs while testing.

the idea is:
it would be nice to add a button or a shortcut key on the page where the userscript is being tested and attach a sort of 'update_extension_and_reload_page' function to it in my userscript, so that evey time when I click this button it will call extension update from the local folder *D:\my-extension* then followed by page reload. (another alternative would be to assign such 'update_extension_and_reload_page' function to extension's  browser_action icon.)

now, I'm just interested:
is there any sort of 'chrome.extesion.update' method,  so that I could make a request to it from my *userscript.js* via *background.js* and call automatic reload of the extension (in "Developer mode") without need to go to the **chrome://extensions** tab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I auto-reload a Chrome extension I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963260/how-do-i-auto-reload-a-chrome-extension-im-developing)

Comment: I don't think it is much of a duplicate: This one is about reloading the extension along with the active tab. The other one is about automating extension reloading "on-save". Besides, applying the accepted answer to this question would mean reloading **all** unpackaged extension and requiring an extra "click" to reload the active page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension can reload itself, by calling **[chrome.runtime.reload()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-reload)**, so it's a matter of triggering the extension to do it.

The code below attaches the following functionality to the browser-action button:

1. Keeps track of the active tab.
2. Reloads the extension.
3. Reloads the active tab.

**manifest.json**

```
...
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Reload"
//    "default_icon": {
//        "19": "img/icon19.png",
//        "38": "img/icon38.png"
//    },
},
...
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    localStorage.tabToReload = tab.id;
    chrome.runtime.reload();
});

function reloadTab() {
    var tabID = localStorage.tabToReload;
    if (tabID) {
        chrome.tabs.reload(parseInt(tabID));
        delete(localStorage.tabToReload);
    }
}
reloadTab();
...
```

---

See, also, **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736675/how-to-reload-a-chrome-extension-automatically#20740389)** on how to automate the re-loading process.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid

Credit goes go

[How do I auto-reload a Chrome extension I'm developing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963260/how-do-i-auto-reload-a-chrome-extension-im-developing)

Comment: Imho so far the best plugin, with shortcut and the ability to refresh the chrome tab as well. Great!

Answer (score 1):

slightly modified the [ExpertSystem's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21227912/3187094) above to call reload of extension followed by reload of tab where the content script (userscript.js) is being performed, all triggered by **#reload-btn** button (in case the browser_action icon is occupied with popup.html).

**manifest.json**

```
...
"background":{ "scripts": ["background.js"]},

"content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : ["https://stackoverflow.com/*"],
        "css": ["userscript.css"],          
        "js": ["jquery-latest.min.js", "userscript.js"],
        "run_at":"document_end"  
}], 

"web_accessible_resources": ["jquery-latest.min.map"],

"permissions": ["tabs"], 

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon19.png",
    "default_title": "My Extension Title",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
...
```

**userscript.css**

```
...
#reload-btn { position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; } /* or any other position on the page */
...
```

**userscript.js**

```
...
$("body").prepend("<button id='reload-btn'>reload extension + page reload</button>"); // some shortcut key can be additionally assigned to this button

$("#reload-btn").on("click", function() { 
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("please, reload me");
});
...
```

**background.js**

```
...
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(message, sender) {
        if (message == "please, reload me"){
            localStorage.tabToReload = sender.tab.id;
            chrome.runtime.reload();
    }
});

function reloadTab() {
    var tabID = localStorage.tabToReload;
    if (tabID) {
        chrome.tabs.reload(parseInt(tabID));
        delete(localStorage.tabToReload);
    }
}

reloadTab();
...
```