# Auto refresh browser on file change?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sublimetext2, osx-mountain-lion

Does anyone know of a plugin or extension that will auto refresh the browser when my project files change?

I'm using supervisor to restart my node server. but hitting refresh every time I want to make a small change is kinda annoying :/

The browser i'm using is the latest version of Chrome on OSX and my editor is Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Did you check out my answer below ? Did it help ?

Comment: http://brettterpstra.com/2011/03/07/watch-for-file-changes-and-refresh-your-browser-automatically/

Answer (score 1):

I wired up gulp and gulp-watch to notify my browser-side javascript to reload the page, whenever I change front-end javascript, html, etc...

Something like....

```
Primus  = require 'primus'
http    = require 'http'
logging = require './logging'

logSpark = (spark, message) -> 
  logging.logBlue('Spark ' + spark.id + ' from ' + spark.address.ip + ' ' + message + ' (now ' + sparks + ' total sparks active)')

# Start sparks server
server = http.createServer().listen(3000)
sparkServer = new Primus(server, { transformer: 'websockets' })
sparkServer.save('./public/script/primus.js');

logging.logBlue 'Sparks server listening on port ' + 3000 + '....'

sparks = 0

# Log spark connections
sparkServer.on('connection', (spark) -> 
  sparks += 1
  logSpark(spark, 'connected on port ' + spark.address.port))

sparkServer.on('disconnection', (spark) ->
  sparks -= 1
  logSpark(spark, 'disconnected'))

exports.broadcast = () -> sparkServer.write('refresh') # arbitrary message text here
```

And in gulpfile.js:

```
watch({glob: "public/*"}, function() {
    clientRefresh.broadcast()
});
```

Plus in the html:

```
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/script/main.js'></script>
    <script src="/script/primus.js"></script>
    <script>
      var primus = new Primus('http://localhost:3000');

      primus.on('data', function message(data) {
        console.log('@@@ refreshing by gulp ' + data + ' request @@@');
        document.location.reload(true);         
        });
    </script>
  </head>
```

I am not familiar with supervisor, but I use nodemon to automatically restart my project's back-end, and have a script that does that plus it starts gulp, which takes care of both types of automatic restart (back-end with nodemon, and front-end with the above).

Answer (score 1):

I made a wrapper around node watch facilities for the purpose of refreshing a web browser on file changes. If you're on OS X then this solution could be a one liner for you.

`npm install -g watchme`

Will install the wrapper. Then save this script somewhere, for example as `~/refresh.applescript`...

```
# ~/refresh.applescript
tell application "Chrome" to tell the active tab of its first window
    reload
end tell
```

Then you use `watchme` to watch specific folder/file/regex on files for any changes. When it detects a change, you execute the applescript to refresh. This essentially simulates the refresh on save that you're looking for, and is totally editor independent (ie, doesn't matter if on Sublime/Vim/Emacs, you're still changing the file)

`watchme app views web -e "osascript ~/refresh.applescript"`

The `watchme` program can be used a bit more expressively, as you can use javascript regex's to match on any files in your project, of particular types. Use `watchme --help` to have a look at the other features.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your node server hold a connection open (i.e. a websocket), and write some code on your webpage so that when that connection dies (the node process restarts), the page calls window.location.reload()

Answer (score 0):

**[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736675/how-to-reload-a-chrome-extension-automatically#20740389)** shows a way to automate the task of reloading the extension. The illustrated technique can be used with a custom Grunt task, an *onSave* hook in youe editor or whatever suits you.

**[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217544/google-chrome-updating-extension-in-developer-mode-locally-from-userscript#21227912)** shows a way to reload the extension along with a tab (useful when you use content scripts).