# Command line chrome extension loading and testing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm currently using the "Developer mode" on the chrome://extensions page of the chromium browser, loading it by clicking on "Reload (Ctrl+R)".

I'd like to be able to make a change to my unpacked chrome extension and load it into the browser in an automated way, especially since I'm testing the extension on a virtual machine so doing all this completely headlessly would be ideal. However, I would at least like to avoid having to click every time I want to load my extension, and I'd like to be able to collect any errors produced into a file/tty.

What is the best way of doing this? Does chrome provide tools for automating extension building and testing?

Regarding the other question linked below:
It doesn't really address my problem, since I am looking for a way to get console output, stack traces and any output generated by the extension reload to be accessible via a file/stream in my OS, as opposed to being displayed in a chromium browser window. The linked answers provide a way to reload the extension programmatically, but not much else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I auto-reload a Chrome extension I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963260/how-do-i-auto-reload-a-chrome-extension-im-developing)

Comment: It doesn't address my problem, since I am looking for a way to get console output, stack traces and any output generated by the extension reload to be accessible via a file in my OS, as opposed to being displayed in a chromium browser window

Answer (score 2):

There are a few avenues for you to research.

1. You could look into [enabling logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) with a high verbosity. In principle, I would think there is a level that echoes console output; I'm no expert though.
2. You could use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to speak to a daemon that will log things for you; the downside is that you probably can't catch errors this way.
3. You could take this one step further and create an extension that attaches to your target extension with [Remote Debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) (which provides the same info as DevTools) using the [`chrome.debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger), and then log stuff with Native Messaging.
4. Or, you could eschew using an extension as a supervisor and just use/write [an external Remote Debugging client](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#remote).

Comment: Thanks, I might look into those. I was thinking of getting swank-js to work and was curious if extensions could be loaded/managed in this way. But currently swank-js is badly or not at all maintained.