# CMD+R not working anymore in chrome://extensions/

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension and previously, to reload the new code, I would just go to chrome://extensions/ and hit CMD+R. Now this is not reloading the extension and I have to manually click (with a mouse!!!) on the CMD+R link.

This is quite annoying and not sure what were the reasons behind this change. Anyone knows of a workaround?

EDIT: Seems this was fixed in the recent Chrome versions.

Comment: Same issue. This really slows dev down.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+R being broken is a bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=526945

Until that bug is fixed, you could use any of the suggestions from [How do I auto-reload a Chrome extension I'm developing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963260/how-do-i-auto-reload-a-chrome-extension-im-developing) to reload extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, true. It used to work before. Note that this reloaded **all** extensions.

Anyway, there are plenty of extensions that will do that for you, e.g. [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid) or many others.

If you're interested in making your own solution, [`chrome.management` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) can do this.

Comment: The above extension doesn't work for me. It does the same Global CMD+R which doesn't actually work. Will have a look at chrome.management API

Answer (score 0):

Here is pretty simple extension that defined two shortcuts to reload all extensions: `Ctrl+Shift+R` and `Alt+R`. Unfortunately, we cannot redefine `Ctrl+R`.

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extensions Reloader",
  "short_name": "Extensions Reloader",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "management",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],

  "commands": {
    "reload1" : {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+R"
      },
      "description": "Reload all extensions"
    },
    "reload2" : {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Alt+R"
      },
      "description": "Reload all extensions"
    }
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon.png",
      "38": "icon.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Reload all extensions"
  },

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

`background.json`:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
  console.log(command);
  if (command == "reload1" || command == "reload2") {
    reloadAll();
  }
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(reloadAll);

function reloadAll() {
  chrome.management.getAll(function(extensions) {
    for (var i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
      var extension = extensions[i];

      if (extension.id == chrome.runtime.id) {
        continue;
      }

      if (!extension.enabled) {
        continue;
      }

      var id = extension.id;

      chrome.management.setEnabled(id, false, function() {
        chrome.management.setEnabled(id, true);
      });
    }
  });
}
```