# http://reload.extensions IP address not found

Tags: google-chrome

I feel like im taking crazy pills.

http://reload.extensions worked just fine for 5 to 10 tries

now I'm getting this error:

This site can’t be reachedreload.extensions’s server IP address could not be found.
Search Google for reload extensions
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I ran it as `window.open('http://reload.extensions')` and also typed it into the url bar

is there a setting I need to enable in chrome?

[How do I auto-reload a Chrome extension I'm developing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963260/how-do-i-auto-reload-a-chrome-extension-im-developing)

Comment: Did you installed the reload extensions extension?

Comment: I did and it works. I don't understand why it doesn't work when i navigate to reload.extensions